# PHP MVC Framework htaccess rewriterule auto add word '?url=xxx' on link

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm beginner of PHP MVC framework, I have learning the PHP MVC framework and already done 90%. All work is almost properly. But ... I have a problem ... i can't solve

After I access the 'name_of_directory' that already exist in my dictory, the link will auto change to localhost/mvc/'name_of_directory'/url='name_of_directory'?, auto add 'name_of_directory'url?='name_of_directory'

example:

```
    localhost/mvc/'exist_dirctory' => localhost/mvc/'exist_dirctory'?url=exist_dirctory'
    localhost/mvc/test             => localhost/mvc/test?url=test
    localhost/mvc/db               => localhost/mvc/db?url=db
    localhost/mvc/public           => localhost/mvc/public?url=public
    ...

    if name not exist on my directory all is working properly
    localhost/mvc/index            => localhost/mvc/index/
    localhost/mvc/help             => localhost/mvc/help/
    ...

    but if i add a backslash behind it work properly
    localhost/mvc/test/            => localhost/mvc/test/
    localhost/mvc/db/              => localhost/mvc/db/ 
    localhost/mvc/public/          => localhost/mvc/public/
```

### My project directory look

```
    mvc
     +config
     +controllers
     +db
     +libs
     +models
     +public
     +test
     +views
```

### .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  ## i want to rewrite also directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I don't want it's keep auto add that thing at my link behind ... can tell me how to solve it ...?

Sorry for my english

Comment: Is the name of the directory always the url value? If so you can just grab it from the URI, so there would be no need for the url $_GET variable

Comment: Davin Jones thank for replay! here is the example problem: [http://mlaxz.com](http://mlaxz.com) i have a directory name called 'test', if you try the link http://mlaxz.com/test it will become http://mlaxz.com/test/?url=test.